# Why my VS Code commits seems like if were made for any one else in Github?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

It is an capture of what I see in my github account...

The "Add and set git ignore file" commits for example, is showed with my name and not my username. It was committed in VS Code and not reflected in my github activity stats. All commits made from VSCode are ignored in github activity stats. What is wrong ?

Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hupw9.png)

Comment: I solved it. Simply set correctly username and email in Visual Studio Code...

`git config --global user.name "GithubUserName"`
`git config --globa user.email "githubaccountemail"`

Since this point the commits author and project author are same person.